# Highchart Solid Gauge Responsive

Tags: highcharts

I created Solid Gauge chart using Highchart.
but when screen resolution changed chart is still displayed with original size.

i need responsive Solid Gauge chart.
[`Demo Link`](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-solid/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solid gauge chart handles size changes quite well by itself. I've [updated the demo JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7d48rwcy/) to show how the gauge can handle resizing.

The main idea here is that when the window is resized, the width of the div is changed by CSS:

```
<div id="container-speed" style="width: 50%; float: left"></div>
```

And the height of the div is changed by JS:

```
function setDivHeight() {
    var div = $('#container-speed');
    div.height(div.width() * 0.75);
    div = $('#container-rpm');
    div.height(div.width() * 0.75);
}

$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    setDivHeight();        
});
```

Note that the ratio between width and height for the gauge seems to be ideal at 4:3, which is why the code multiplies by 0.75 to set the height.

Managing the text elements will be CSS/JS/HTML positioning and resizing of your choice, depending on how many screen sizes you wish to handle.

Comment: another issue i have with same chart is i want to display only start and end point on gauge. comment if you have any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution manages responsivity in both vertical and horizontal direction. Furthermore, it does not require additional JS to resize the container div.
Check this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/istibekesi/bm3d1zng/

Highchart sets the height of the chart to 400px by default.
So the trick is to set the height of the chart by percentage:

```
#container-speed {
  height: 180%
}
```